# angular jasmine-node not installing via node npm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm, jasmine

I've tried a few times to install my first AngularJS project via their docs:
https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/contribute

```
*# Clone your Github repository:
git clone "git@github.com:<github username>/angular.js.git"
# Go to the AngularJS directory:
cd angular.js
# Add the main AngularJS repository as an upstream remote to your repository:
git remote add upstream "https://github.com/angular/angular.js.git"
# Install node.js dependencies:
npm install
# Install bower components:
bower install
# Build AngularJS:
grunt package*
```

Each time I try to npm install it returns an error for jasmine-node

[image]

I've searched for solutions and tried a bunch of methods & hopeful tests but still not receiving back any luck.

Much appreciated for any help, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An issue I was frequently experiencing was protocol issues due to npm errors being returned especially for Bower.

You can make git replace the protocol for you. Just run:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Apologies if this thread is a bit of a mess, but hope it helps someone out there too.

Answer (score 0):

Those docs are for people who want to contribute (work on angularjs library) and not for people who are building projects *using* angular. To me, it seems that you'd want the latter.

There are plenty of tutorials out there, just search for `angularjs beginner tutorial`, and find the one that suits you the most.

Comment: I've tried getting it up and running with all these methods:
1. https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/ ***************
2. https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/started
3. https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

All coming back with errors. 

I'll continue you looking for a solution

Comment: Angular-seed should be the easiest. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRrL5j3MIvo - helped me (unrelated to angular-seed)

Comment: This should be a comment, and not answer